# Modify Array.append function?

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm working on some multidimensional structures. Most functions to manipulate space data are defined as an extensions for `Array where Element: SpaceAxisProtocol`. If an array has four axes it's mean space has four dimensions. OK. But in some structures inside `Axis` I need another arrays, which length and data depends on [Axis] elements number. If I have three axes in Array, `axis.someAddidtionalInfo` array count must be equal to 2^3, for four 2^4 etc.
I know how to change content of those arrays, but I have no idea is it possible to somehow change `append` or `remove` behaviour to change those values in Array extension. I know I can build some struct `Space` to control `axes:[Axis]` and use `didSet`. For some reasons I try to avoid it if not necessary.

```
extension Array where Element: SpaceAxisProtocol {
   // if self was modified do something with elements
}
```

Even possible?

Comment: This is really weird, nothing you're describing here is an `Array`. Make your own `struct` or `class`.

Comment: There are arrays in another structures and classes <Axis:SpaceAxisProtocol>, defined as ‘axes: [Axis].

Comment: If I leave like this, every `axesArray.append()` or axesArray.remove() will cause the data inside array elements will be not consistent. If I will move all functions form array extensions to Space class or srtuct, I will need to refactor all code I wrote till now.

Comment: "data inside array elements will be not consistent." Yes, that's precisely why Array is an inappropriate choice of data type for the situation. `Array` is meant to store an ordered sequences of homogeneous elements. Anything more than that is no longer an array, and belongs in its own well-defined struct or class (which itself could use arrays internally, if you wish).